# Variables are not initialized only the first time when selecting a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have parent view with a list of subviews in a scroll view. When launching the app the first time, if I click on one of the subviews in the scroll view, a new view appears but the variables that are passed to it are not being initialized in the view. If I navigate back to the parent view and select another subview or the same one again the variables are initialized with the correct vars, why does it not work only the first time? I tried waiting a few second before picking a subview to allow the view to render but that does not work, I have no errors in my code also.

```
struct ExploreView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ExploreViewModel()
  @State var imageArray: [String] = ["final", "final2"]
  @State var scaleDis: [Double] = [0.7, 0.5]
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  @State private var showDiscover = false
    
  @State var image: String = ""
  @State var scale: Double = 0.5
    
  var body: some View {       
    VStack {
                
      ScrollView {
        LazyHStack {
          ForEach(imageArray.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            Button {
              image = imageArray[i]
              scale = scaleDis[i]
              showDiscover.toggle()
            } label: {
              DiscoverRowView(imageName: imageArray[i], scale: scaleArray[i])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDiscover) {
      DiscoverView(title: title, imageName: image, scale: scale)
    }
  }
}
```

```
struct DiscoverRowView: View {
  @State var imageName: String
  @State var scale: Double

  init(imageName: String, scale: Double) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.scale = scale
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
      ZStack {
        Image(imageName)
          .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
          .scaleEffect(scale)
          .offset(y: -15)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is titleArray ?

Comment: BTW, you are doing common mistake : you have multiple element but only one Bool value.

Comment: @PtitXav I updated my code, titleArray wasn't supposed to be there

Comment: In SwiftUI they call it a "Store".

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is already the view model so it is pointless to make a view model object. And it's crazy to use `@StateObject` for it. The View struct and `@State` structs is all you need for your view data.

Comment: @malhal so you want me to out everything in one big view file, like noodle code? What's wrong with using StateObject I don't see any downsides

Comment: No, many small View

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code that shows a misunderstanding of how SwiftUI works.

This code in particular...

```
ForEach(titleArray.indices, id: \.self) { i in
  Button {
    image = imageArray[i]
    scale = scaleDis[i]
    showDiscover.toggle()
  } label: {
    DiscoverRowView(imageName: imageArray[i], scale: scaleArray[i])
  }
}
```

The way that you should be using `ForEach` is `ForEach(titleArray) { title in ...`

But then the button is odd too...

```
  Button {
    image = imageArray[i]
    scale = scaleDis[i]
    showDiscover.toggle()
  } label: {
    DiscoverRowView(imageName: imageArray[i], scale: scaleArray[i])
  }
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but this is not correct. I think you're trying to set an image for the button. But this is not how SwiftUI works.

I'd recommend checking out the free tutorials that Apple provide for learning SwiftUI basics. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

It looks like you have a `titleArray`, `imageArray`, and `scaleArray` that are all related to the same item. In that case you should create a struct to hold this data...

```
struct MyModel {
  let title: String
  let imageName: String
  let scale: Double
}
```

And then use an array of `[MyModel]` in your view...

```
let models: [MyModel] = [
  .init(title: "Title", imageName: "final", scale: 0.7),
]
```

Then in you foreach you should use that to display the title image etc...

Start from the tutorials though. I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I'm not sure I can help fix it.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, none of what you mentioned will solve this issue, creating a structure is just another way to make my code my readable and simple. How can I solve the issue of the data not being passed when I load a subview the first time.

Comment: @jacksonswswsw well right now that doesn’t matter. Your code is all over the place. Doing `image = imageArray[i]` is not doing anything in your button. So even if imageArray has content you’re not doing anything with it. I’m surprised that would even compile. Fix the basics then we can work on the more complex stuff.